# How do I get barrier blocks in bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create my own minecraft server and I need barrier blocks to prevent players from going to certain places. I already know how to get command blocks but I don't know the command to get barrier blocks.

Comment: I would assume that it's the same, but with `barrier` or `barrier_block` or similar.

Comment: I would like to point out that, using the /give command, or any command really, will show suggestions based on what you've typed. When you type /give, for example, it shows a list of all items and blocks that can be obtained through the command. Typing /give @s bar automatically shows barrier as the only option available for that command.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command:

```
/give @s barrier
```

For some reason the namespaced ID of barriers isn't listed on [its own wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier), so I went to [the list of Bedrock Edition data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_data_values#Block_IDs) to find it.